# Reference list entry for tweets

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apacite

I want to cite a tweet for my paper, currently i´m trying to get the right entry in my reference list.

I´m using Latex with Texstudio and biblatex. My citation style is `apacite`.

My MWE looks like this:

```
   \documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
    \usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
    \usepackage{microtype}      
    \usepackage{color}                  
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage[hyphens]{url}
    \usepackage{breakurl}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,draft = false,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue] 
     {hyperref}
    \usepackage{apacite}
     \begin{document}
      \tableofcontents
      \clearpage                        
      \listoffigures 
      \listoftables
      \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
      \bibliography{lit_memes} 
       \end{document}
```

The entry i want to get should look like this:

Musk, E. [@elonmusk]. (2020, June, 26). *Who controls the memes, controls the universe* [Tweet]. Twitter.
https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1276418907968925696

The citation in text would ideally look like this:
(Musk, 2020)

I tried using the `@misc` type in my `.bib` file, i already got close to what i wanted but couldn´t actually get it.

I´d be very happy, if somebody has an idea.

Thanks in advance!

Lukas

Comment: Why not use `@online`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply,
i guess i´ll try the ´´´@online´´´ type. Unfortunately i can´t find anything in the package documentation about it, do you know, which fields can be used?

Comment: You should use  `biblatex-apa`,  it will be easier to customise. See biblatex documentation, p.11, for the fields associated with @online.

Comment: Hi, please excuse my many questions, but i´m quite new to Latex so i don´t know a lot about it.

I tried replacing the `apacite` package by the `biblatex-apa` package, but this didn´t work since this package doesn´t exist. Then i tried using `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` but this didn´t work with my own defined commands. 

Do you know any way to customize @online with `apacite` ?


Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know really how to customise bibtex styles (they use Polish reverse notation). The biblatex does exist (there's even a biblatex-apa6 package), but you don't have it installed, I suppose. Just install it with your package manager. The syntax you used was correct for loading biblatex.